# Animated Sorting of Block Elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page where I want to animate the sorting of a list of block elements.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-block">
    ....
    </div>

    <div class="content-block">
    ....
    </div>
<div>
```

I want something similar to the sortable elements provided by jquery ui but it will animate based on an event not based on dragging. I can write it myself but I'm wondering if there are any good libraries out there to handle it.

Comment: What type of sorting as you talking about, to make them fit coherently, or are they the same size being re-ordered?

Comment: @Nick they are fixed width but not fixed height elements. Think stackoverflow answers moving up and down based on vote order, I want them to actually move over and under each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write this myself. using the .animate() method. setting z-indexes and altering the positions of the elements. One thing that might be useful is animating one div and animating the other in the first animate's `step` event binder

Comment: Yeah I guess building it from scratch is probably the way to go. Thx.